# Where should the Dative object be placed when it is a proper name?

Tags: dative, accusative, proper-noun

I know that there are a variety of situations in which the dative and accusative objects can be placed differently.

As far as I know, the following sentences are correct:

> Ich gebe ihm das Buch.
>   Ich gebe meinem Bruder das Buch.

But when the akkusative object (das Buch) turns into a pronoun (es), the sentences are formed like this:

> Ich gebe es ihm.
>   Ich gebe es meinem Bruder.

So my question is: **What if I wanted to use a proper name** like *Herr Müller* instead of *ihm* or *meinem Bruder?*

Would it be correct if I said:

> Ich gebe es Herr Müller.

Or do I have to use an additional preposition such as *zu* and say:

> Ich gebe es zu Herr Müller.

Comment: It's been *implicitly* but not *explicitly* mentioned in the answers you got so far: There's no difference in the placement whatsoever whether the object is a proper name or any other sort of object.

Comment: 'Herr' is inflected **Herrn** in the dative, accusative, or genitive case: "Ich gebe es {Herrn Müller}ᴰᴬᵀ. Ich rufe {Herrn Müller}ᴬᴷᴷ an. Das Auto     {Herrn Müller**s**}ᴳᴱᴺ  / des {Herrn Müller}ᴳᴱᴺ / von {Herrn Müller}ᴰᴬᵀ ist silberfarben. "  ('Frau' and  'Fräulein' remain unchanged in all cases.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Basic thoughts

The basic situation has already been clarified by the previous answers. I would like to add that the first word order that comes to mind is:

> Ich gebe Herrn Müller das Buch.

This can emphasise, the object, but usually not strongly. There are certainly other permissible word orders. The first one would be:

> Ich gebe das Buch Herrn Müller.

which normally emphasises the recipient. Of course verbal stress plays a role. Then there is a case for contrasting recipients. What they receive also gets stressed, albeit less:

> Herrn Müller gebe ich das Buch, Nina die Gitarre!

Naturally, there are cases where stress becomes a major aspect:

> Das **Buch** gebe ich Herrn Müller, das **Geld** aber Nina.
>
> **Das** Buch gebe ich Herrn Müller, alle anderen aber Nina!

### About *es*

Usually – there are exceptions – when we use *es,* it receives very little emphasis and often only serves grammatical correctness. Hence, we pick an order not emphasising it:

> Ich gebe es Herrn Müller.

### Proper nouns

Having pondered for a few minutes, I can’t discern anything special about proper nouns:

> Ich gebe dem Hund den Knochen.
>
> Ich gebe ihn dem Hund.
>
> Ich gebe Herrn Müller das Buch.
>
> Ich gebe es Herrn Müller.

### About *zu*

In this sense, adding *zu* is not permitted. Adding *zu* often invokes significant changes:

> Ich gebe es zur Reparatur. – I gave it away **for** repair.
>
> Sie gab das Mädchen zu den Nonnen. – She gave the girl to the convent (probably for education)
>
> Ich gebe Salz zur Suppe. – I add salt to the soup.

About the last example, I am not sure if it is idiomatic. I tend to express it differently.

So if we correct your example, adding an *n,* it may occur, albeit in a very different sense from what you probably thought. For instance, we may have:

> Ich habe ein kleines Mädchen. Ich gebe es für ein halbes Jahr zu Herrn Müller nach London, damit es Englisch lernt!

Answer (score 3):

It’s not necessary to write *zu* because the verb *geben* is already a dative verb:

> Ich gebe Herrn Müller das Buch.

If you prefer to use pronouns:

> Ich gebe es [the book] ihm [Mr. Müller].

If you want to write his name in the sentence, then it is:

> Ich gebe es Herrn Müller.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the dative should be placed at the end of the title, "Herr."

The proper construction then is "Ich gebe es Herr**n** Müller."
The "en" comes after the "Herr" and is contracted to "n."

There is also an omitted "dem." That is, it is omitted from "Ich gebe es [dem] Herrn Muller.

You don't need the additional preposition "zu" for "to," because this idea is embodied in the dative.